# How do I count the frequency of letters in a string and sort by alphabetical orders?, if their frequency is 1, ignore them

Tags: python, string, frequency, alphabetical

Given string S consisting of only lowercase letters (a-z). Print to the screen all the letters that appear more than once in the string S and their number in lexicographical order.

```
a = input()
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a.count(a[i])!=1:
        print(a[i], a.count(a[i]))
```

the problem here is it does print the frequency, but doesn't sort in alphabetical order, and some letter and their frequencies it print out more than 1

example input

```
thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
```

example output

```
e 3
h 2
o 4
r 2
t 2
u 2
```

How do I do this pls help

Comment: Use a dict to store the counts, then sort its `items` before printing?

Comment: can you be more specifically? for example how to use dict and sort, sorry I'm new to python so I don't know

Comment: Your question looks like homework, so it should be possible to answer it with the material that already got covered in your course. You might also want to have a look at some good Python tutorial, see for example a list at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F . SO is not really meant to replace that.

Answer (score 1):

Make a mapping of letters to counts. One quick way with a dictionary would be:

```
word = input()
letters = {}
for letter in word:
    if letter not in letters:
        letters[letter] = 0
    letters[letter] += 1
```

You can simplify this using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word = input()
letters = defaultdict(int)
for letter in word:
    letters[letter] += 1
```

Or even simpler with a counter:

```
from collections import Counter

word = input()
letters = Counter(word)
```

Now that you have your letter counts, you just need to sort and print the items:

```
for letter, count in sorted(letters.items()):
    if count > 1:
        print(letter, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

s = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"

d = {}
for c in s:
    if c in d:
        d[c] += 1
    else:
        d[c] = 1

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

for k, v in od.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(k, v)
```

store the letters and their appearance in a dictionary, sort it and print the key and value if the value is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Used `collections.Counter` for frequency of characters. Only lower case characters were considered.

```
from collections import Counter

my_string = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"
threshold = 1 # exact value or more

# frequency of characters in string
cc = Counter(my_string.lower())

# infer alphabetical ordering
res = sorted(cc.items())

# output
print('\n'.join(f'{char} {freq}' for char, freq in res if freq >= threshold))
```